# Что значит(,) тебе «не разрешают»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, цитата, диалог

Подскажите, будьте добры, как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

> — Сделай сам.
> — Мне не разрешают.
> — Что значит(,) тебе «не разрешают»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думается мне, что последнее предложение в диалоге не совсем корректно.

Если используется цитирование, то считаю, что оформление должно быть таким:
*— Сделай сам.

— Мне не разрешают.

**— Что значит «мне не разрешают»?***

Или таким:
*— Сделай сам.

— Мне не разрешают.

**— Что значит «не разрешают»?***

Сказуемое "значит" здесь употреблено в значении "означает" — запятая не нужна.
Вот [пример](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85/) из ПАС (под ред. В. В. Лопатина; §139):

> А после моих слов он улыбнулся от уха до уха (рот у него такой, как раз от уха до уха) и радостно согласился:
> — Ну ладно, тогда пойдем.
> «Вот я тебе покажу „пойдем“», — подумал я про себя.

P. S. В сборнике немного другое оформление ([В. Солоухин. Камешки на ладони](https://thelib.ru/books/vladimir_solouhin/kameshki_na_ladoni_sbornik-read-4.html)):
*«Вот я тебе покажу «пойдем»!» — подумал я про себя.*

Answer (score 2):

Я бы расставил так:

— Сделай сам.
— Мне не разрешают.
— Что значит «тебе не разрешают»?

В данном случае кавычками выделяется не цитата - кавычками выделено то, значение чего спрашивает второй человек ("Что значит «(...)»?").

Постановка запятой, как здесь:
— Что значит, тебе «не разрешают»?
Не совпадает даже с интонацией ("Что значит, «(...)»?"); да и вы же не пишете, например, "Что такое, «успех»"?" вместо "Что такое «успех»"?" .

Answer (score 1):

Попробую выразиться яснее.

**Я считаю правильным ответ user 99579,** причем это в первую очередь касается **замены местоимения.** Мне такая замена представляется **обязательной**, иначе это будет ошибкой. И я привожу два реальных примера из литературы, где такая замена делается.

**1) Александра Маринина  "Светлый лик смерти".**

– Он уже заплатил, – сообщила секретарша...

– Заплатил? – запыхавшись, радостно спросила Люба.

Мила подняла на нее холодные голубые глаза, не прекращая своего занятия.

– МНЕ – да.

– Что значит «ТЕБЕ – да»? – не поняла Люба. – А мне?

– А тебе – нет.

**2) Михаил Гиголашвили. Чертово колесо (2007)**

Ищут наркотики:

— Ладно, все в рабочем порядке. Прямо сегодня и начните прочесывать по реальному списку, — велел майор...

— Да, это в точку! Я уточнял — директор магазина тканей … — сказал Пилия.

— Его я беру на себя! — перебил майор, но тут Мака заскрипел стулом:

— Нам, значит, комсомольцы и коммунисты, а ТЕБЕ — директора базаров и магазинов?

Пилия удивленно обернулся к нему. Майор развел руками, досадливо объяснил:

— Что значит — МНЕ? Нам, нам! Мы, по-моему, вместе работаем! Ты брось эти штучки — мое, твое!

**КОММЕНТАРИЙ**

Итак, во втором примере (перед единичным местоимением) кавычки не поставлены, но замена местоимения тоже делается (тебе – мне).

Римма в своем ответе исправляет авторский вариант, но это **ошибочное исправление**, как мне думается. И я не вижу у нее примеров, где не делается замена "мне – тебе" или "тебе – мне". В моем же первом примере ясно видно, что без замены текст становится некорректным.

Интересная тема с этими местоимениями – всегда она вызывает вопросы. Поэтому мне было бы интересно выслушать другое мнение и увидеть примеры, его  подтверждающие.